# XACML 3.0 Request with additional Attribute is matching even that attribute is missing in the policy rule

Tags: authorization, xacml, xacml3, abac, wso2-identity-server

I have a XACML 3.0 policy defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Policy 
  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" 
  xmlns:xacml="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17 http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-core-v3-schema-wd-17.xsd" PolicyId="Proposal-Rules" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
  <Description>Policy for any proposal.</Description>
  <PolicyDefaults>
    <XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</XPathVersion>
  </PolicyDefaults>
  <Target />
  <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="ApproveProposalByDepartmentChair-Rule13a">
    <Description>"Department Chair" can "Approve" a "Whole Proposal" when ApprovedByDepartmentChair = READYFORAPPROVAL and where condition check all department chairs are not approved.</Description>
    <Target>
      <AnyOf>
        <AllOf>
          <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Department Chair</AttributeValue>
            <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:position.title" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false" />
          </Match>
          <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Whole Proposal</AttributeValue>
            <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:proposal.section" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false" />
          </Match>
          <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">READYFORAPPROVAL</AttributeValue>
            <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:ApprovedByDepartmentChair" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false" />
          </Match>
          <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Approve</AttributeValue>
            <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:proposal.action" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false" />
          </Match>
        </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
    </Target>
    <Condition>
      <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:boolean-equal">
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:boolean-one-and-only">
          <AttributeSelector MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" Path="//ak:signedByAllChairs/text()" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean"/>
        </Apply>
        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean">false</AttributeValue>
      </Apply>
    </Condition>
  </Rule>
</Policy>
```

My XACML request looks like this with an extra AttributeId="group" containing value "Computer Engineering".

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
                <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
                    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:position.title" IncludeInResult="false">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Department Chair</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:group" IncludeInResult="false">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Computer Engineering</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
                    <Content>
                        <record xmlns:ak="http://akpower.org">
                            <proposal>  
                                <signedByAllChairs>false</signedByAllChairs>
                            </proposal>
                        </record>
                    </Content>
                    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:content-selector" IncludeInResult="false">
                        <AttributeValue XPathCategory="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:data-type:xpathExpression">//ak:record/ak:proposal</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:ApprovedByDepartmentChair" IncludeInResult="false">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">READYFORAPPROVAL</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:proposal.section" IncludeInResult="false">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Whole Proposal</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
                <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
                    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:proposal.action" IncludeInResult="false">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Approve</AttributeValue>
                    </Attribute>
                </Attributes>
    </Request>
```

I was hoping the PEP going to return **NotApplicable** but on contrary it returns following response: with **PERMIT** 
Even though the defined Policy Rule doesn't contain any Attribute called "group" as Rule Target whereas the request is sending "group" attribute with value "Computer Engineering" and even it is returning match and PERMIT response!

```
<Response xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17">
    <Result>
        <Decision>Permit</Decision>
        <Status>
            <StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:status:ok" />
        </Status>       
    </Result>
</Response>
```

Is there something I am missing? I could not figure it out. I am currently using [Balana](https://github.com/wso2/balana) as PEP implementation for my application.

Comment: You only included the rule. Do you have the entire policy?

Comment: BTW your snippet is missing a closing <Rule/> element

Comment: And you need to define the namespace for the prefix ak

Comment: Hi @DavidBrossard I update the whole Policy with all details for your reference. My concern is why the request with 2 subjects attribute is not validated even existing only one valid subject makes the rule return PERMIT rather it should return NotApplicable response

Comment: You also have an incorrect XML snippet... You wrote <record xmlns:ak="http://akpower.org">... but shouldn't it  be <ak:record xmlns:ak="http://akpower.org">?

Comment: Your XACML is actually full of mistakes. Did you write it with WSO2 IS? This, for instance, cannot be a boolean...<AttributeSelector MustBePresent="false" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" Path="//signedByAllChairs/text()" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#boolean" />

Comment: Also your request is invalid. It is missing the closing <Request/> element

Answer (score 2):

I have now managed to import your policy inside the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point.

### Basic Issues

You had several mistakes:

1. Your XPath expressions uses a prefix `ak:` (`Path="//ak:signedByAllChairs/text()"`) but the XPath doesn't contain the definition for ak:
2. The AttributeSelector is marked as a boolean but text() in XPath returns a string, not a boolean. You need to change to string.
3. The XML snippet part of the XACML request `<Content/>` does not actually use the ak: prefix. It does define a namespace with that prefix but never uses it.

### Representation of the policy in APS

[image: Representation of the policy]

### Simulating the policy

I simulated your policy and did not get a Permit back. I get Indeterminate. Here is the evaluation trace. There must be something wrong in WSO2 IS or you forgot to deploy the new policy.

[image: Evaluation trace - Axiomatics Policy Server]

Now, if I clean up the XML you send to have exactly this:

```
<record xmlns:ak="http://akpower.org">
    <proposal>                  
        <signedByAllChairs>false</signedByAllChairs>                    
    </proposal>
</record>
```

then I get Permit back from the policy.

Comment: :Please read my clarification for your mentioned Issues
For 1 and 3: I already include xmlns:ak as namespace that is defined within the root level of <Request xmlns=".." so there is no need to write xmlns:ak just ak works fine and XpathExpression is returning exact content data

For 2. I don't think this is an issue because I already tested and it compares false as boolean value rather string. If you know please let me know how to get boolean value in similar way as keyword text(). Or if you think this is an issue do I need to send string value in request for all boolean type!

Comment: Can you please re-run the simulation with the modified policy (updated in the question with spaces removed). Actually, I thought the result must be Indeterminate as the Request has additional **group** attribute that doesn't match in any rules in the policy.